# Java app no longer runs under OS X 10.11 El Capitan

Tags: java, macos, launcher, osx-elcapitan

We have a set of Java applications that have been working fine on OS X for years.  They work fine on OS X 10.10.

A few people just upgraded to 10.11, and one of the apps no longer runs.  It gets a:

```
com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.oneshot.0x10000004.OSXJavaLauncher[395]) Service exited with abnormal code: 1
```

Error in the console, and never starts at all. (icon shows on the taskbar for just a second.)

Our other app starts just fine.  It is built with the same Java Launcher code.

Is there any way to find out what OS X doesn't like about the app that fails to start?

Comment: Only way is debugging, lldb, write logs to console. My guess is that your crashing app does something that takes down the launcher as well.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the actual Java app never starts. The first thing we do is turn on the app's logging, and nothing gets written.
Since this is working on all previous OS X versions, I was hoping somebody would have run into this, and can tell me what changed.

Comment: If you cannot pass application did finish launching then I suspect nib awaking. Try to do a sample app and try to launch it with Java Launcher. At least you know whom to blame (crashing app or the launcher).

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same problem,  basically even with [Java for OS X 2015-001](https://support.apple.com/kb/DL1572?locale=en_US) installed my app wouldn't start.  In researching this problem, I came across information on this [github page](https://github.com/tofi86/universalJavaApplicationStub), which does a really good job of explaining the issue.  In short, Java apps built into native executables for mac using older tools will no longer work because of incompatibilities in the plist format, and applicationstubs.  Apps built for Apple's java are not running with Oracle's java and vice-versa.

Using the information from the referenced page, I rewrote our ant build using this [ant task](https://github.com/tofi86/Jarbundler), and this [application stub](https://github.com/tofi86/universalJavaApplicationStub).  I now have a native app that runs on both Apple's Java 6 and Oracle's Java 8 and runs in testing on OSX 10.9-10.11.